# Jquery not compatible with box-sizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Currently all I'm trying to do is grab the height of a div using

```
$(header).height()
```

Header being a div element.

Current in my css I have the following:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This means that all padding, borders, etc does not effect the total size of the element. And It seems to be working just fine. 
But when I make an equation with `$(element).Height()` and an object has padding or a border, it adds those extra sizes to the dimensions of the div even when `box-sizing` is set to `border-box`.

## Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/CeuBQ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that as I was writing the question I figured out the problem.

Apparently, the div doesn't actually keep it's dimensions using `box-sizing:`, but the border or padding subtracts from them. An interesting thing I must say, I would have never thought that.

Though, to get the real height of the element you need to use jQuery's outerHeight function that includes the padding - border and so on.

`( $(headerPad).outerHeight() );`

**Fixed:** http://jsfiddle.net/CeuBQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$(header).height()
```

to

```
$(header).innerHeight()
```

jquery `.innerHeight();` will exclude padding and border and only count width;

Comment: No, in fact I need the outer height. The padding was subtracting from the total width because of my `box-sizing` property.